# Does cinnabar react with iodine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, organosulfur-compounds, mercury

Does cinnabar react with bromine and iodine to form elemental sulphur? This reaction was described in "Explorations in the history of science and technology in China" but I have doubts...[image]

Comment: "…reports$^{22,23}$" — you sure have checked these reports, haven't you? Also, what is "*Explorations in the history of science and technology in China*", an article, a book, a report or a blogpost? How are we supposed to check these references?

Comment: 1. I did not verify the possibility of the above mentioned reaction experimentally.

2. Explorations in the History of Science and Technology in China . A Special Number of the " Collections of Essays on Chinese Literature and History . ” Shanghai : Chinese Classics Publications House, 1982.

Answer (score 3):

I did a cursory search and found some information particularly from books of late 19th century(1,2):

**Cinnabar and iodine**

> On heating, it (cinnabar) is readily decomposed with formation of small scarlet crystals of mercuric iodide.

**Cinnabar and bromine**

> [...] After digesting the cinnabar with excess of bromine liquid (or bromine water containing 3% of bromine or solution of hydrochloric acid containing 13% of bromine) for a few days, the whole is dissolved, and also any metallic mercury present [...] The amount of bromine required is very considerable, 1 part of mercury is obtained and 3.5 parts of hydrobromic acid remains in the solution.

**References**

1. Chemical News and Journal of Industrial Science, Volumes 37-38, Chemical news office., **1878**
2. Dictionary of Arts, Manufactures and Mines by Robert Hunt, Andrew Ure, **1878**